# Why is my jquery ajax POST function sending my form data to my base url rather than to the url I specified?

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, forms, post

I have a form that I would like to **POST** data to my backend.
I have successfully prevented myself from being redirected when submitting the form. I want the POST request to go to `MYBASEURL/form`.

The code below almost works, however the Ajax call seems to ignore my specified URL, and makes a POST request to MYBASEURL.

What I'm using:

**jquery-1.12.3.min.js**

**Node.js v4.3.2**

**Express 4.x**

**bodyparser**

```
<form name="myform" action="#" method="POST">
  Username: <input type="text" id="user" name="username"/><br/>
  Password: <input type="text" id="email" name="email"/>
  <input type="submit" id="submitForm" value="submit"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var user=$('#user').val(), email=$('#email').val();
  $('#submitForm').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/form",
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'text/json',
      data: JSON.stringify({name:user, email:email}),
      complete: function() { /* Do something with the response. */ }
    });
    return false; // Prevent form submit.
  });
</script>
```

Changing the relative url to an absolute url changes nothing.
Removing the '#' from action changes nothing.

How can I ensure this POST is going to `MYBASEURL/form/` rather than just to `MYBASEURL/`?

Comment: try using full url .. may be declare a ajax_base_url global for javascript and use it here like url : ajax_base_url +'/form'

Comment: Changing the relative URL to an absolute URL does not fix or change my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding my own answer as I had a problem on both my frontend and backend:

First the variables weren't initialized in the right scope, my script should have been like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#submitForm').bind('click', function() {
    var user=$('#user').val(), email=$('#email').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "/api/users",
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify({name: user, email: email}),
      complete: function() { 
        // Do something with the response.
      }
    });

    return false; // Prevent form submit.
  });
</script>
```

This allowed my `$.ajax POST` to correctly send to the correct path: `MYBASEURL/form`

My second problem was understanding that I had to set my back-end to correctly parse content type that matches the type specified in this ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem is in this code. After solving the errors in the code you posted (setting a 'user' var but submitting a 'username' and $('#subitForm').bind instead of $('#submitForm').bind), and it works fine. I would wonder if you have some sort of routing happening via .htaccess or otherwise.

Comment: If you would like to elaborate more on .htaccess that would be great. Is that related to the backend? My backend is in Node.js/express if that matters.

I've assumed that this is a frontend problem since I AM able to receive GETs and POSTs and etc on my different routes.

Comment: Deleted my first comment after re-reading what you said.

Ok so after fixing these coding errors you're saying it IS a backend problem. Thanks!